# MD5 signature not match

Tags: php, md5

I'am in the process of adding paymentwall to my wesite but I keep getting an error with their md5 signature everything I try says "ERROR: Signature doesn't match".
I would really like some help if anyone can.
Thank you

```
$secret = "xxxxxxxx";
$userId = isset($_GET['uid']) ? $_GET['uid'] : null;
$transactionId = isset($_GET['ref']) ? $_GET['ref'] : null;
$points = isset($_GET['currency']) ? $_GET['currency'] : null;
$sig = isset($_GET['sig']) ? $_GET['sig'] : null;
$action = isset($_GET['type']) ? $_GET['type'] : null;
$ipuser = isset($_GET['userIp']) ? $_GET['userIp'] : "0.0.0.0";

            // validate signature
        if (md5($userId.$points.$action.$transactionId) != $sig){
            echo "ERROR: Signature doesn't match";
            return;
        }
```

I got this it of info on paymentwall after idk what to do with it
Signature base string

```
uid=1currency=11type=0ref=rrrrrrrr2621097ba7ef27f468946f05799688a4
```

Signature = MD5(Signature base string)

```
efdd4e86decba4537212eaebac993b7e
```

Comment: What is `$secret` for?  How is `$sig` being generated?  Have you checked that all 4 of the values used in the `md5` are what you think they are?

Comment: What's paymentwall?

Comment: Given that sig string, you'd probably want something more like `md5("uid={$userID}currency=.....")`

Comment: before the if statement, please put this and tell me what do you see: echo md5($userId.$points.$action.$transactionId) . '<hr>' . $sig . '<hr>'; die();

Comment: Ii got 70525976108c60c302305eea957a99e1 on top AND
95fb21ead960bd349973d81e1fca69ab at the bottom in the echo

Comment: Hi, I am also getting similar error from api like 'wrong signature error' for cancel subscription. have you any idea about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got the MD5 to work now just wanted to let you know.
I had to use the paymentwall api instead and it deals with everything for me)